# History of mathematics in engineering

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I am starting out to teach a course in calculus for (first semester) engineering students. I woild like some soure book (or other kind of sources) for "history of engineering mathematics". Searching for that term at amazon.com does only give general history of math books.  Anybody know some good books, links, etc for such info?

EDIT: to answer the question in the so far one answer: let us concentrate on calculus-based engineering mathematics, that is, post-Newton! We can also concentrate on mathematics used in some central fields like mechanical engineering and civil engineering (that is, constructions).

Comment: I'm probably going to find myself in the same situation as you this fall, in which case I'm planning on trying out Toeplitz's historically-based introductory calculus text (http://www.press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/C/bo5485725.html) at least as a reference for my own lecture preparation.

Answer (score 1):

Engineering is a vast field. It would be easier to find material of the kind you are looking for if you narrow down what specific applications you have in mind. Kepler, Euler, and Cauchy were closely involved in applications of the calculus to engineering. As far as modern references are concerned, there is one specific application that might be of interest:

Gourlay, Tim P. A brief history of mathematical ship-squat prediction, focussing on the contributions of E. O. Tuck. J. Engrg. Math.  70  (2011),  no. 1-3, 5–16.

Comment: "History of Strength of Materials" by S.P. Timoshenko is an interesting read on the history of the strength of materials.